# Besides Impact, what JavaScript game engines exist?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, game-engine

Pls don't include subjective thoughts, or moderators will close this question like they closed our last one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668076/impact-vs-other-javascript-game-engines).

We need game engines that can run on iOS devices and ideally Android devices as well.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't need any subjectivity, wouldn't Google work just as well?

Comment: Frankly, we prefer subjectivity, but the last question was closed because it fostered too much debate. This is better than Google because we can see which game engines have greater consciousness in the SO community, which is a crude proxy for penetration, which itself is a crude proxy for utility.

Comment: the reason i prefer asking question like this here as opposed to google is that people can speak of their personal experiences/shortcomings of the project, etc.

Comment: "or moderators will close this question like they closed our last one" Ah, I see: "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a site which contains a big list of JS game engines:

http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/f094j/list_of_js_game_engines_community_effort/

Also, if you're interested in this sort of thing, you might want to subscribe to the [Javascript Weekly](http://javascriptweekly.com/) newsletter (or at least read the back-issues from their site). This newsletter is a great way of keeping up-to-date with the latest news in the Javascript world, including news about new JS libraries that come out. Game libraries have features quite often.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How does impact and javascript know if the game is to be displayed on a mobile device or a regular monitor.

Comment: @DougHauf - That's a really big topic; you probably want to ask it as a separate question, there's too much to explain to pic it in a comment here.

Answer (score 3):

[Crafty javascript](http://craftyjs.com/) game engine also exists.

Comment: which one do you think is the best. I have heard good things about impact but I want the games to run equally on the computer as they wou would a phone or tablet. I even think that they can be downloaded on the WII U. Not certain on the last part.